# Why does Google's OAuth2 documentation recommend storing a profile ID in a cookie?

Tags: go, google-oauth

Google's [OAuth2 documentation for Go](https://cloud.google.com/go/getting-started/authenticate-users), titled "Authenticating Users with Go" and involving a bookshelf example application, suggests storing the profile information in a cookie. See, for instance, the profileFromSession() function, also [visible in GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/getting-started/bookshelf/app/auth.go#L161). That documentation says "Because the profile information is stored in the session, it can be retrieved by the application without fetching it again from the Google+ API". It stores the Google+ ID and DisplayName (via the [plus.Person](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/plus/v1#Person).ID and plus.Person.DisplayName).

But isn't that bad practice? Doesn't it make it easy for clients to fake the user profile, letting them access any user's data in your application by just putting a different user ID in the cookie?

When getting the profile from the cookie, it first checks if the token is valid, but that only checks locally if the token struct contains an access token and if it has expired, without any communication with Google's servers. Surely it would be possible for a client to construct a fake cookie with an arbitrary profile ID. The cookie is encrypted (see http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions#NewCookieStore ), but only symmetrically, making the encryption key the only obstacle to this attack.

Google's [equivalent Java OAuth2 documentation](https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/authenticate-users) seems to do the same thing.

Have I misunderstood something? I can't believe that Google's documentation would recommend something so insecure.

Answer (score 1):

The example uses [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) to prevent cookie forgery.

More details: The example use Gorilla's [securecookie](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/securecookie) package to access cookies. This securecookie package uses the  [crypto/hmac](https://godoc.org/crypto/hmac) package to sign and verify cookies.

If the cookies are sent over a HTTPS, then a third party cannot steal a cookie.

The securecookie package's encryption feature plays no role in preventing forgery or theft of the cookies.

Comment: Thanks. But that signing is just using a symmetric key, right? So if you have that secret key then you can access any user's data by creating a fake cookie with an arbitrary user ID? Well, I guess the same would be true of a private key if it did (asymmetric) public key signing, but I assume that it's easier to discover a symmetric key via analysis of many signatures (looking at many cookies in this case).

Comment: The package prevents this attack by using a secure hash algorithm.

Comment: There is one (pretty obvious) gotcha: the use of a secure cookie *must* only  go hand in hand with https/ssl connections. The cookie is a bearer token: anyone using it asserts ownership of the account it specifies without further question. Therefore it is *essential* to protect the network transfer of the cookie using SSL.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong to assume that symmetric encryption is inherently more vulnerable (than public/private key encryption) to a brute force attack to discover the secret key.

Comment: @murrayc  See the wikpedia articles on [cryptographic hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) and [hash based message authentication codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).  Encryption plays no role in preventing cookie forgery with these packages.